# MYSQL How to find entries that contain more than 10 numbers?

Tags: mysql

I need to clean up a table that contains a lot links to images. I can identify them by the name, because they include a lot numbers.

Question is how does the query looks like? Is it possible?

```
WHERE table REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

This brings me every entry that contains a number.

But what I need are all entries that contain at least 20 numbers.

Example: /dsc-2342342432423432424234234

thanks again

Comment: `[0-9]{20,}`? ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for at least 20 digit  ..

```
select * from my_table 
where my_column  regexp '[0-9]{20}'
```

Comment: Per the OP: _"But what I need are all entries that contain at least 20 numbers."_...